# 1 question with new activity

Tags: support, live-refresh

Just noticed this here on Meta:

[image: screen shot]

Cool, any details? Could not find any `status-completed` questions mentioning this. :)

This message appears all by its own after I leave the browser open for some minutes (~5) and coming back. Clicking the message is displaying the new question, same result as reloading the page.

Comment: Phantom feature...

Comment: I'm not really sure how cool this is; what useful information does it really convey? *Which* 1 question is it that has new activity? Is the text a link to the question? And is it by chance referring to a question that you have favorited? I don't see it on my home page... :-(

Comment: @Cody sorry, wasn't clear in my description.. see my edit.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I can reproduce this now. We're just like Twitter. And YouTube.

Comment: @Cody and Facebook..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Please don't say the F word on Meta.

Comment: I don't see the message. `:(`

Comment: @kiamlaluno just leave the home page open on the `active` tab and leave - if you come back after enough time you should see it. The counter might "reset" if you browse other pages in the site, even from different tabs or browser..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We are testing pushing new updates to the homepage via web sockets as they happen here on Meta only for the moment.  Both the inbox notifications and new activity will occur without the need to constantly refresh.  As soon as we can prove this works here on meta we will roll it out to the rest of the network.

Comment: Cheers! Looking good so far, you got any estimation when it will be rolled out? :)

Comment: Will that also work for the flag count?

Comment: eeek you added a cheese!

Comment: I'd especially be interested in the flag count, like @Fabian said.

Comment: @Geoff - Just noticed this on Electrical Engineering.  I take it that it's been rolled out to the rest of the network?

Comment: @KevinVermeer we have rolled this out to all of the network sites except for Stack Overflow.  There are more changes coming as well related to updating real time.

Answer (score 14):

Considering this:

- [Stack Overflow, refresh. Refresh. REFRESH. REFRESH!!!!!!!! NOW!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121476/stack-overflow-refresh-refresh-refresh-refresh-now)

was marked as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) recently - I'm guessing it just got rolled out to Meta :-)

Comment: I've not noticed this on other sites, so I guess they're testing it on MSO first.

Comment: @ChrisF yes, I meant Meta-only - added that :)

Comment: Yeah, Geoff (who is a developer, not mere moderator) marked it this way but never got back to my comment to explain.. 20 days later we now see this - no coincidence!