# Disregard natural activity feed timeframe when refreshing page after "1 new item with activity" is clicked

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

I noticed that when new content is loaded by clicking the [link that reads "X question(s) with new activity,"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity) everything loads properly. But when I refresh the page after that (perhaps to check for an update to my rep, the automatic ones for which come up not too often), the new content that was shown earlier is gone because of the natural rate at which the front page is updated.

It would be neat if the newly loaded questions would remain, even after refreshing the page, and regardless of the natural timeframe within which the front page updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We still have a few improvements to make to the realtime updates including a faster refresh of the existing tabs.  We are continuing to advance the goal of getting your questions answered as fast as possible even after a "natural refresh" or F5 - if this is what you want to call it.

Comment: Great to know, thanks Geoff. Is this one specifically in the works? Faster natural refresh time for the front page is good and all, but it'd be awesome if the content I saw stayed there after the refresh.

Comment: Yes, it's all part of the plan.

Comment: Awesome. 7 minutes and I'll accept. Thanks for the update!