# Add a slight delay to "question(s) with new activity" notice after refreshing the whole page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, live-refresh

I've seen it happen more times on SuperUser than here, but several times the page has barely finished rendering and then the notice pops up:

[image]

Maybe people like this instant notice that the site is "alive", but I find it annoying that I've *just loaded the page* and the notice is telling me that the information is slightly stale and I must click on the page to get a current version.

I think a slight delay would alleviate this "omg, my new page isn't new anymore!" experience.  Maybe 10-15 seconds after page refresh before popping up the new activity banner?

If not a delay, maybe it would be smoother to just insert the new activity into the questions list if it happens in the first few seconds?

Based on [Geoff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124181/157384) it seems the goal is to get these updates as fast as possible - but I guess I just don't see the purpose in telling people that their freshly loaded page isn't fresh.

Comment: maybe they can adopt a twitter-like interface for that, just maybe

Comment: @prusswan: Seriously?  Twitter is now being held up as a model for state-of-the-art development techniques?  The world is coming to an end...

Comment: @Robert Harvey the point is to have the new posts queued at the top behind some drop down mechanism to minimize the amount of distraction. I'm not advocating a twitter clone and besides, state-of-the-art development may not have much to do with usability

Comment: ... **why**? What's the point of this? Do people really get *upset* when they see this on a page that they've just refreshed? Or do they just clicky and go about their business? Is this really providing a negative user experience?

Comment: @CodyGray yes!  Not giving a user enough time to skim the page before you inform them "this page is outdated, but you have to click to find out more" is indeed a degraded experience.

Comment: Adding a delay defeats the purpose of having "instant" notifications on the site when things change.  The goal is for it to be as fast as possible.