# Live refresh does not render $\LaTeX$ (MathJax)

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, live-refresh

The [live refresh feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity) doesn't take MathJax into account. Here's a screenshot of the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) after clicking on “$n$ questions with new activity”:

[image: math]

I saw the same effect on the CS private beta.

I'm running Chrome 17.0.963.65 (stable) on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MathJax will now be rendered on the live refresh after the next build.

Comment: Confirmed on [math.se] under rev 2012.3.9.1549. Thanks, that was fast.