# Live refresh doesn't render MathJax (again)

Tags: bug, mathjax, live-refresh, regression

[This old bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125096/295232) is back: this is how the [recently active questions page on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active) looked like after clicking '1 question with new activity':

> [image: math questions with and without rendered MathJax]

and this is how it *should* look like, and actually does after hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>:

> [image: math questions with rendered MathJax]

Comment: Looks like another classic case of "Hey, this line of code appears useless, let's remove it". ;)

Comment: It’s been like this for years. It’s news to me that it ever was fixed.

Comment: And this time an (automatic) regression test will be added?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum hahahaha. haha. Yeah. good joke. :D (aka they have us, they don't need automatic tests)