# What's the meaning of numbers in parentheses in the name of a tab?

Tags: support, design, stack-exchange

Why are there sometimes numbers in parentheses in the title of a page?

For example,`(5) Stack Overflow` or like this:

[image: Number in title]

Comment: possible duplicate of [1 question with new activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Mark stated - this is the number of new active questions with activity updated as they happen.  We have rolled the realtime active questions update to the entire network except for Stack Overflow where there is no active tab.  We are planning on adding updates to other question list pages by tag in the near future so stay tuned.

Answer (score 4):

It denotes how many new posts with activity have surfaced since you last refreshed the page, as described in the MSO question, [1 question with new activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity):

> We are testing pushing new updates to the homepage via web sockets as they happen <strike>here on Meta only for the moment</strike><sup>1</sup>. Both the inbox notifications and new activity will occur without the need to constantly refresh.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: has since been deployed to a number (if not all) of the sites on the network.