# Meta-synonym: [web-sockets]-->[live-refresh]

Tags: discussion, meta, synonym-request

Synonym/merge please (on MSO):

[web-sockets](/questions/tagged/web-sockets)-->[live-refresh](/questions/tagged/live-refresh) --[they refer to the same new voodoo feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity)

Or merge both to [realtime-updates](/questions/tagged/realtime-updates) (nonexistent), since that's the common term.

[Link to synonym page for convenience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/live-refresh/synonyms)

Comment: I created a few with [tag:web-sockets]. [tag:live-refresh] is much better. +1

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Whoa whoa.. This request is for the _MSO_ tags...

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise `[tag:metatag]` linked to the tag on the main site. I meant to refer to the meta tags.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: to link to meta-tags use `[meta-tag:waffles]`. It even properly formats(in a post) the red status- tags and the compulsory tags (bug/discussion/feature-request/support)