# Can the live-updating also load the content of the post?

Tags: feature-request, javascript, live-refresh, ajax, web-sockets

Could the live-updating box auto update everything? Instead of showing a box, why not:

1. Just get the new post content, unless you're on SO
2. Do this:

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
   var activity = $('.new-post-activity');
   activity.click();
}, 1000);
```

This would auto click the box, meaning the new answers/questions/edits will show up.

NOTE: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity) is what I'm talking about.

Comment: What live updating? You mean the banner?

Comment: @TIm yep that one

Comment: No thanks. I don't like auto growing pages like FB

Comment: If this were to happen (which I wouldn't want!), SE would probably remove the box entirely and probably use `$.get("/posts/ajax-load-realtime/{postIdsSemiColonDelimited}?title=true".formatUnicorn({ postIdsSemiColonDelimited: post.id }), refreshPost(div.find('.postcell, .answercell'), post));` as soon as it receives the WebSocket info, so they'd edit the `postEdit()` function to remove the box and auto-refresh the post.

Answer (score 4):

I have thought of it often too, and it seems a nice feature to have. The problem is though that when you are reading the front page, it is very annoying that it constantly scrolls down to make place for the new content (this is the same for questions and answers, which could benefit from the same auto-update functionality).

I agree this issue is a lot smaller argument on low-traffic sites since the posts aren't changing that frequently, but still then I wouldn't like the page to scroll away to make place for new content.

What I would like see is that it updates posts that are already there. There is no scroll-down necessary to update the *modified*, *answered by X*, etc. which often causes the notification to appear.

Comment: If the modified timestamp was updated inline, what about reordering?

Comment: No, I don't think that is good. That will still cause the reader to lose the post he was reading.

Comment: Yes apologies, that was my point; this would lead to the posts being out of order. Is that not a problem?