# Can the "new activity" indicators somehow be combined to avoid playing whack-a-mole with them?

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

I like the [new real-time updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox). It has really eased the burden of my left hand's index finger repeatedly hitting "F5".

However, my right hand's index finger seems to have taken on the burden, as I find myself clicking every notification that pops up, particularly with very young questions that are getting many new answers and comments in a short time.

It's kind of like a game of whack-a-mole right now:

> "Ooh, new answers! *click*. What's this, more comments!? *click* Another answer! *click*."

I understand that it'd probably not be ideal to automatically show the new activity, since it'd result in the contents of the page shifting around uncontrollably.

However, would it be possible to aggregate the notifications somewhere so that I only have to click once to get all of the new answers and comments, etc.?

Or perhaps there's a different way to solve this as well. I'd be interested in others' ideas.

Comment: "so that I only have to click once to get all of the new answers and comments, etc." -- Recommission your F5 index finger for this! =)

Comment: @BenLee - I find myself still doing that anyway out of habit.