# SO Feature Request: Add an ajax update / refresh routine for Top Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Due to @lunboks' answer, I decided to reword the request.  I understand the the main SO page (Top Questions) has a ton of questions, so it was decided to not put a live updater there.

Can't we just add a greater interval for that page, since there are so many questions?  That way it's not constantly incrementing? Maybe put it on a 30 or 60 second timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already implemented, but it's not active on the main homepage on Stack Overflow specifically because of how big it is. Tag views (try [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) for example) already do live updates.

See the [announcement of the live update feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox):

> All sites **except for Stack Overflow** have a new activity indicator on the homepage which will show when new posts are asked or answered.
>   [...]
>
> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

Just think about how many questions SO gets. By the time your browser has finished rendering the new questions, there'd be more of them.

Comment: I understand. I still would like the opportunity to see a block level element that would allow me to load the new questions vs having to right-click reload. Seems more user-friendly.

Comment: @Scott Why do you have to right click to refresh?

Comment: `Ctrl`+`R` works just fine. The questions *already* scroll by too quickly for me to handle.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I'm not really trying to debate the various refresh methods. I know I can do F5, CTRL + F5, right click + Reload/Refresh, click the refresh button in the address bar, etc. I'm just saying in general, it would be nice on that main Top Questions page to have what the others have.  If it's too big, it could simply be done on a greater interval.

Comment: @Scott Sorry, didn't mean to get derailed on the refresh thing.  Do you see that it *does* work for the question page as long as you're filtered by a tag?

Comment: @jadarnel27 - Yea, I did see that. I guess I never sort by tag due to the fact I want to sort by "all" of my tags and that's not there either. So, I just stick to Top Questions.

Comment: @Scott: clicking on the Stack Overflow logo reloads the top questions page.