# What technology/framework is Stack Overflow using to asynchronously update clients?

Tags: support, technology

While the notification about there being new answers to a question you're currently answering has been around for a while, I've noticed more recently Stack Overflow seems to be sending other updates to the client theses days:

- Indicating new questions since page load when you have a search page open
- Reputation auto updating
- Date fields auto updating (created date/ edit date)

So I was wondering technology/framework is Stack Overflow using to push these updates to the client? (Custom AJAX? A JS library?)

I've looked at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369)'s answer, but I don't see any specific mention.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Geoff Dalgas's post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox), they're using Web Sockets

> Now for the gotchas - in order to use this feature you must have a
>   browser that supports web sockets. See:
>   http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets for a list of browsers that
>   currently support web sockets.

Comment: Yep .. no fugly longpoll fallback. I was happy when I read that because it gives me something 'major' to point at where time wasn't wasted on trying to make bonus features work for every browser under the sun.

Comment: OMG this doesn't support IE 5.2 for mac? OUTRAGE No seriously good on them for designing for the future/present

Answer (score 1):

According to [Marc Gravell](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain) in Jan 8, 2019,

> As of late 2018, Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange) have migrated away from NetGain, instead using Kestrel's inbuilt web-socket support over HTTP/1.*; it is entirely possible that as we delve more into HTTP/2, we look more in the direction of SSE (EventSource).