# New questions are not shown immediately in Chrome

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions, google-chrome

I've recently changed my default browser from Firefox to Chrome. Now i'm not able to see new questions until i hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

What can cause this issue since Chrome 21 does support Websockets as confirmed [here](http://websocket.org/echo.html)? Note that I'm not using a proxy or firewall and it works without a problem in FF.

If it's still unclear what feature i'm referring to: 
[What technology/framework is StackOverflow using to asynchronously update clients?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129499/what-technology-framework-is-stackoverflow-using-to-asynchronously-update-client)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/C%23%20or%20VB.NET%20or%20LINQ%20or%20T-SQL%20or%20SQL) is my favorite link (*newest* tab).

> On SO or on other sites?

A moment ago i've tested it in Superuser, it works there, also here on Meta! So why should Stackoverflow make an exception?

Comment: On SO or on other sites? The SO home page doesn't change automatically. I do see “X questions with new activity” with Chrome.

Comment: @Gilles: I've yet tested only SO, i don't see the "x-questions with...". This is my favorite link: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/C%23%20or%20VB.NET%20or%20LINQ%20or%20T-SQL%20or%20SQL

Comment: I thought the feature was completely disabled on SO. Did you get “X questions with new activity” on SO with Firefox?

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, even just now.

Comment: I can confirm that I don't get updates with Chrome 21 on http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23 . I do get them on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 . It seems that SO isn't getting live updates for the tags in the Unanswered tab. [This announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) seems to say that this is by design (in that in only mentions live updates on SO in the “newest” and “active” tabs).

Comment: @Gilles: Make it an answer and i'll accept it. My FF-link uses the questions tab instead. Thank you!

Comment: Same on Firefox, but *only* on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be by design. According to the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox), live updates are:

- enabled on tag pages of SO, but only in the “newest” and “active” tabs;
- disabled on the main page and the unanswered tab of SO;
- enabled on all date-ordered full question lists (newest, active, unanswered) and the corresponding tag pages on other sites.

So you should expect live updates on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 but not on https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23, and that it what I see with Chrome 21.