# What does StackExchange use web sockets for?

Tags: support, web-sockets

Just curious -- when I refresh a random SE site's home page, I see a message in my JavaScript console:

> [18:50:38.128] De verbinding met ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ werd onderbroken tijdens het laden van de pagina. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=ee8dc25807f6:13

In English, that would be something like...

> [18:50:38.128] The connection with ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ has been interrupted during the pageload. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=ee8dc25807f6:13

What is this web socket for?

Comment: In addition to the vote counter, comments, new answers, and post edits will also show in real-time via web sockets.

Comment: @Mysticial okay, thanks :) perhaps you could make it an answer?

Comment: Insilico has it. I think this question is a dupe anyway.

Comment: Or perhaps a better one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129499/what-technology-framework-is-stackoverflow-using-to-asynchronously-update-client

Comment: @Bart Maybe this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Websockets on the Q&A site proper are used for [live updates to the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/1-question-with-new-activity) and for [live updates to questions, answers, and your inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox). <strike>The chat subsite (https://chat.stackoverflow.com) also uses websockets to implement the live chat function.</strike> The chat subsite does use websockets, but I'm not positive of its actual function.

This feature has been implemented for a while now. You can check for new features here: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)