# Real time updates get lost when navigating back to a page

Tags: bug, live-refresh

I love the [real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) we have now, since my <kbd>F5</kbd> key was starting to wear out.

There's one scenario though that still makes me refresh manually. I'll illustrate for questions:

While looking at [Recently Active 'javascript' Questions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=active), suddenly banner reading

> 1 question with new activity

appears. I click it, and the most recently active questions, `Question B`, appears on top of the other questions:

```
Question B
Question A
...
```

I open a question that looks interesting. After reading it, I navigate back, and `Question B` disappeared from the list.

That would be alright **if** they came back with the next real time update. Sure enough, the banner reading

> 1 question with new activity

pops up after a few seconds. To my surprise, now I have

```
Question C
Question A
...
```

and `Question B` went to limbo until I refresh the page.

Real time updates to answers, comments and edits behave similarly.

Comment: I believe this is due to server cache that updates once in a minute or two rather than back button issue.

Comment: Reproduced. Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and wait for "1 question with.." to appear.Click it. Refresh the page with F5 and... question is gone!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your browser caching the page.

When the browser recieves the page, it stores a copy of the recieved page with itself--so if you hit the back button, you get to see this cached page. You can test this by opening a random page, clicking a link on it, disconnecting yourself from the Internet(noooo!), and hitting 'back'--the page will still load.

On the other hand, new stuff which happens to the page is not cached. IIRc, sombrowsers *do* cache normal JS/etc, but maybe not websockets/AJAX (not sure if thus)

So this is a browser issue, not an engine issue.

Update:

I'm quite sure the realtime updates work on a "push a new change as it comes along" system. To fix your [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), the behaviour will need to be changed to "push the 'new changes' list every xyz seconds", or "AJAX-fetch the question list on page load". Both solutions blow up bandwidth (former more than the latter), and the latter is just redundant.

---

Update2: OK, there *is* a server-side cache issue. Can has fix?

Comment: No. I just proved it's a server cache: go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and wait for "1 question with.." to appear.Click it. Refresh the page with F5 and... question is gone!

Comment: @Sha then it's both, since I've noticed(and just reproed) this problem when two tabs are open simultaneously--one refreshed and one 'back'ed--if I wait long enough before f5/back-ing, then the f5d page is OK, but the backed page lacks a question.

Comment: @Manishearth: I realize that the browser loads the page from cache in its original state. If I just had to wait for `Question B` to reappear, I wouldn't have tagged my question `[bug]`. But `Question B` going to limbo isn't expected behavior.

Comment: @Dennis I would expect this behaviour--the websockets will push _new questions as they come_. It won't compare the question feed with what questions are already there (Educated guess on my behalf) . So that's supposed to happen. It still is a sort of [bug]/[feature-request] hybrid though--the only way to fix this is to change the behaviour of the live refresh to push the entire feed every xyz seconds. That will be a lot of extra bandwidth wasted.

Comment: @Manishearth: I admit that I don't know enough about websockets to fully comprehend the situation. That's why I didn't want to tag it `[feature-request]`, since I cannot actually propose a solution or behavior. But there must be **some** way to save `Question B` from an eternity in limbo...

Comment: @Dennis I don't understand websockets much either, but I'm quite sure that this must be the implementation, since the alternatives (listed above) are bloat-y without any payback(except cache). To save the question, refresh. I know it's annoying, but supporting browser cache will be extremely bloat-y, IMO. I _can_ write a Chrome extension that _may_ fix this by hijacking your "back" button and adding a randomness tail on SE pages, but I'm not sure--never written one before.

Comment: @Manishearth: Maybe there's a way to store the current state locally.

Comment: @Dennis interesting, though that still complicates stuff

Comment: "new stuff which happens to the page is not cached." - okay, but if you do something that actively needs to communicate with the server (e.g. vote on something or edit a comment) surely it should make an AJAX request at that point, and refresh the page contents? Or at least the relevant portion? I have found that it doesn't work for editing comments, for example - the edit field will populate with the browser-cached comment, not the one currently on the server.