# It shows old question in newest tab

Tags: bug

But the question those are added by websocket are recent, just clicking on tab shows older questions

[image]

**Found to be working fine now [10:47 GMT]**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real time updates get lost when navigating back to a page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130976/real-time-updates-get-lost-when-navigating-back-to-a-page)

Comment: It was observed at  10:37 GMT time

Comment: @Tim its not the same, Please verify

Comment: It's the same issue. Server-side caching of the newest tab/main page/etc

Comment: Oh, I see. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132713/newest-questions-are-from-yesterday

Comment: I accidently deleted my quesions with the same issue here. it happens on every browser no matter if I am logged in or not and even if I never open SO with that browser. And suddenly it works again.

Comment: **Seems working fine now**

Comment: Looks like server cache hiccup.. for how long did it happen?

Comment: @Sha for like 10-15 min

Comment: I saw this at around the same time today too - http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/970151#970151

Comment: It's happening again http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132929/old-question-in-newest-questions-tab

Comment: No, its working fine

Comment: I've been playing with systems; almost certainly this was just cache lag as I switched systems back and fore