# Old questions in newest questions tab

Tags: bug, questions

This is a duplicate to [it-shows-old-question-in-newest-tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132712/) (which was closed).

It happened yesterday for me too the same time as it did for the poster of that question.
After a few minutes it was working again. Now it happens again.

In newest quesions tab, questions from yesterday are displayed.

### Edit:

Now it is working again. Time elapsed: about 10 minutes.
<strike>**The interesting thing is that it happened yesterday at the same time.**</strike>

Comment: Since it's the second time this happened, I think this ought to be left open and not closed as "too localized"

Comment: No, not the same time. That was at 10:35 UTC, this is 8:37 UTC. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/132712/timeline and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/132929/timeline .

Comment: Yup, exactly the same thing just happened to me. I asked about it in chat, but no one else around could repro it. It's working again now. Strange bug.

Comment: @TimManishEarth: Are you sure? When I click on the comment I left there then it displays about the same time as when I asked this question.

Comment: @juergend: Mouseover the comments above. They're 9:00. That page has comments at 10:37 onwards. No biggie, but if it was happening at the same time every day it would probably be easier for the devs to isolate (a misplaced `cron` job or something)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was almost certainly me, flipping a big [molly-guarded](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/M/molly-guard.html) switch between two implementations of the same system - the old stable version, and the new experimental version. The main gotcha is: if I've been using "stable" for a while, and then switch to "experimental" (as I have been doing periodically), then it goes back to a slightly older version of the data. It will quickly notice that it is old and refresh itself, but then caching etc kicks in... yada yada yada blah blah blah it might have shown some older tag-oriented data for a few minutes when it flipped over.

If it keeps happening, please do let me know.

Comment: hey @MarcGravell, that bug happened again

Comment: @Lucifer yes, I just flipped a switch; should catch up in a moment. I will try and tweak the switch-over code to do a hard update *first*

Comment: ok @Marc, it looks like it is working fine now.

Comment: I had same problem this morning and posted it (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133369/stackoverflow-date-problem): did you flip the big molly-guarded button again? :)

Comment: @Marco briefly, yes

Comment: It just happend to me on SO but works again now.