# Why are all questions' posting time displayed as yesterday

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old question in newest questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132929/old-question-in-newest-questions-tab)

I login into the Stack Overflow site from India and 18-May 8:40 AM (GMT) and click on Questions tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions

All question are showing that they are asked yesterday.

[image]

How can I see the latest question that were posted today?

Comment: Its working fine now.

Comment: What is your computer time set as? I am guessing it is set to tomorrow.

Comment: It's displaying 18-May-2012 02:13 PM (IST) indian time that is GMT + 5.30

Comment: It **was** yesterdays questions. I recognized some of them, including one I helped delete yesterday. That one shouldn't show up at all today.

Comment: Now the question is this why I was not able to see today's question. You can see the image that I am on "newest" tab.