# Why is the Facebook mini-site occasionally showing all Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

A couple of times today I've noticed the Facebook mini-site everybody loves is showing all Stack Overflow questions, not just Facebook related questions. This occurs on the [new question list](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions). Here are a couple of screenshots of examples (it happened to be both logged in and not logged in):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I thought at first they had [listened to us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership) but then I refreshed and it was working again.  Then I refreshed and it wasn't.

Comment: When was this? It might be related to the issue reported recently where the "newest" tab was out by a day. Something about caching: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132944/153020

Comment: Perhaps on a fresh page load it gets only FB questions, but the ajaxy new question loader notification thingerizer loads all new SO questions?

Comment: Note that the "Featured" tab shows the number of the mini site though.

Comment: @awoodland about 2 minutes before I posted.

Comment: I'm seeing it right now, does indeed "feel" like what @awoodland links to. (Editing C++ questions via facebook.SO just feels dirty, I'm out of there.)

Comment: Aww, I thought this was a new feature where they dump all the bad questions onto the Facebook site. There are already so many terrible questions there, I'm surprised anyone noticed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sigh... Me again. I've been deploying some experimental code changes to the way our tags are handled... I guess something in sub-sites wasn't applying the sub-site completely. I've switched back to the stable version for now.