# Clicking on Question button in Stackoverflow not showing latest questions in newest tab

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old questions in newest questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132929/old-questions-in-newest-questions-tab)
>   [StackOverflow date problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133369/stackoverflow-date-problem)

When I am clicking on Question button on stackoverflow.com then newest tab then it is showing me the questions of 18th May instead of today's questions. In the morning it was working fine but before 10 minute it is showing this behavior.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132929/173001

Comment: this may be duplicate question. Is this a regular behavior?

Comment: No, this is not regular behavior. Something went wrong. Already reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133369/stackoverflow-date-problem), too.