# Very old questions in "Newest" in advanced tag search

Tags: bug, tags, tag-search

I just did a search like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost+or+boost-phoenix+boost-spirit+boost-spirit-qi+boost-spirit-phoenix
```

I highlight the "Newest" tab, but note the dates on the bottom half of the screen;

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: I can't see the dates on the bottom of the screen because you massively suck at cropping (and with linking to full-size versions of images).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can teach you a new trick then, http://i.stack.imgur.com/iwWKl.png (note, I didn't implement the feature that broke click to open fullsize; I sure think that used to work)

Comment: Repro and this appears to only affect page 1

Comment: I shouldn't have to furtle about with my browser. Could you fix the post, please? You only need to put the image within a link to the same image. The Markdown formatting FAQ can help you to write a link in your post. And like I say, a little cropping really wouldn't hurt...

Comment: [Possibly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132929/254929) question from a while back.

Comment: @Lightness [if it's bugging you that much...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/240279/edit)

Comment: @AirThomas except, it's not "shortlived" here: http://i.imgur.com/Zt3I5By.png (taken just now)

Comment: @AirThomas: Why should _I_ have to do it? OP has a responsibility to not post massive uncropped screenshots. That I have the ability to fix this mistake for him does not change that fact!