# Delayed refresh when hitting 'Questions'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, recent-activity

There is something a bit weird I noticed lately: When the message 'Question with new activity' pops up at the top of the questions list and I click the 'Questions' button instead of the message itself, the new question mysteriously vanishes for a few minutes or so, no matter how often I click 'Questions' again. Basically it looks like the polling time for the bar is much shorter than that for the 'Question' button. Did anybody notice this?

Comment: Yup, I noticed that too.

Comment: So there's no fix? Maybe it's just me, but I find it kinda annoying.

Comment: You could flag this question to be migrated to [metase], there'll be people more knowledgeable about this issue. I'd assume though that it'll be [tag:status-bydesign] because the live update and the normal update work in very different ways.

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks, will do.

Comment: Whoops. I totally misread the post, pardon the duplicate vote. This is, however, somewhat related to [Real time updates get lost when navigating back to a page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130976)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

The *Questions* page is heavily cached, so it can take a couple of minutes for new questions to appear.

Since pushing new questions via Web Sockets is a lot less expensive, there's no caching (or less) and they appear much faster this way.

> When [...] I click the 'Questions' button instead of the message itself, the new question mysteriously vanishes for a few minutes or so[.]

The obvious solution is: Don't do that.

Real-time updates have been designed specifically to prevent this delay **and** reduce the load on the servers.