# Does the reputation at the top update live, too?

Tags: support, reputation, live-refresh, top-bar

I'm wondering whether the reputation in the top bar automatically updates...

*If so, I need to get rid of an extension that does the same.*

Comment: Yes, it does. More or less live.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does.

From [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox):

> **UPDATE** 
>   As a few have mentioned below we are now experimenting with updating comment counts, votes on a post, and your reputation score.

There's current one exception (bug?) though: Downvoting somebody else's answer doesn't seem to change the reputation.

Comment: The extension that `brings Live reputation updates to the StackExchange™ EgoEmpowering HumanWorth™ counter` has been disabled, thank you for your co-operation in this mission to figure out why my reputation dropped each time I switched page after gaining reputation. :)