# Real-Time updating changes my reputation at top, but not user card

Tags: feature-request, reputation, live-refresh, user-card, top-bar

This is not really a bug with the system, just something I noticed when [viewing my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10514291/138383) on SO when it was upvoted.  I've read how many are on the fence about this new change, but I'm a big fan of the [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677/180510).

You can see the top reputation value was updated with the upvote, but my user card on the actual answer still shows the original reputation value.  I'd imagine both would be changed with the real-time updating.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxyRs.jpg]

Comment: Why are you bothered about this. The next time you refresh the page or view another page it will be updated.

Comment: It would make sense that both would update since it's showing the same information in two or more places on the page. It's a suggested improvement.

Comment: @AaronW. You should replace your [bug] tag with [feature-request] then.

Comment: We don't update other users' cards (it'd be quite unreasonable to do so), this would be more confusing than helpful IMO.

Comment: Since it's related, we had a brief [discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=926083#926083) about this once. Note that the real-time updates also don't respect the tab sort order when loading new answers, but that would similarly be a change that might confuse users more than the current behaviour.

Comment: I realize to be consistent you'd want to update all user cards on the page.  Though when I see the upvote happen, and my rep at the top increase it'd make sense that it would reflect across the whole page on my user cards....thinking more about it I see the issue when it's not my answer on the screen and their answer gets upvoted should their user card(s) be updated?  Damn that's a backend mess I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't *do one but not the other*.

If you're going to update it at the top, then update it on the rest of the page.

If you don't want to update it on the rest of the page, then don't bother updating it at the top.

I mean you do want to reduce the number of spurious 911 calls, don't you?