# Live update of reputation does not update user card

Tags: bug, reputation, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real-Time updating changes my reputation at top, but not user card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131947/real-time-updating-changes-my-reputation-at-top-but-not-user-card)

Just a minor note, when you accept an answer it updates the top of the screen but not the little icons elsewhere on the screen.

After having accepted an answer on the page:

> [image: Two more rep on top than in the user card]

Comment: Your eyes are staring at your eyes staring at your rep discrepancy.

Comment: If you refresh the page, it will update.

Comment: @Arjan I see you're right. will clarify my answer.

Comment: Well, it *is* a bit more complicated to update that piece.  The one at the top is **guaranteed to be there**.  You may or may not have a user card on the page you're viewing.  So it's a (possibly expensive) operation for dubious benefit.

Comment: How long are you sitting on a single page that this matters? I really don't need Ajax or jQuery keeping every single person's rep on a single page perfectly up to date as their rep changes based on activity on thousands of other questions.