# Different reputation level in the answer and in the popup

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I found strange behaviour of displaying the reputation in SO. Surprisingly, I haven't found any topic in Meta regarding this.

Here is an example. In the answer repo looks like **18.8k**:

[image]

When I hover, in the popup we see **18.7k**:

[image]

The exact repo level was **18,796** and it haven't changed for all the test period. Moreover, several times I have updated the page and the same difference remained.

*Bug*? or I didn't get something?

Comment: related: [Real-Time updating changes my reputation at top, but not user card](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131947/real-time-updating-changes-my-reputation-at-top-but-not-user-card)

Comment: @YannisRizos related, but not really the same.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA That's what I said: related. Where do I say they are the same?

Comment: @YannisRizos u ddnt :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Caching - the user popup is aggressively cached.  Stop getting so much rep in a day :)

Comment: Yep, you're right. Now I have updated the page and the repo in the popup is on the same level as in the answer. I didn't believe that caching is soooo aggressive, not being in time with my slow answers today :)