# x questions with new activity / x new answers to this question not working

Tags: support

These two features stopped working for me since a couple of days. I have to refresh the browser every now and then to see newly posted questions/answers.

is it only me ? or is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

EDIT : after trying the [link](http://websocketstest.com) @ShaWizDowArd gave me, these are the disconnected parts :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not good with sockets so I wouldn't know what they mean :)

Comment: on which page ? stackoverflow.com/questions ??

Comment: @NullPointer yes in stackoverflow and I search for a certain tag like C# for example

Comment: @NullPointer It doesn't work in meta as well

Comment: looks fine to me  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uybxe.png

Comment: Did you change browser by any chance? When you browse to [this test page](http://websocketstest.com/), what you see? Also, you might have installed new anti virus [that is blocking web sockets](http://superuser.com/questions/423163/firewall-blocks-websocket)..

Comment: @NullPointer thats weird. is it something to do with connection speed?

Comment: @AbZy speed isn't relevant it's using web sockets connection with the server. Kind of "live AJAX".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd websockets 80 and 8080 not connected. everything else is fine

Comment: @AbZy so that's your answer. What browser? What anti virus you have?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've always been using Firefox and it used to work. I haven't installed any new anti-viurs. been using windows security essentials

Comment: Well, nothing to do with Stack Overflow then, see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153678/152859). Try using Chrome, hopefully its web sockets are still working.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I downloaded Chrome and it worked. could you please edit your answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Comment: Done, though it's still bit strange what caused Firefox to stop liking web sockets. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You probably switched to different tab by mistake.</strike>

The live updates are present only in the active tab, e.g. [active tab for C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#?sort=active&pagesize=50).

As it currently stands, the site "remembers" your last tab so once going to other tab, any time you visit a tag page it will go to that tab.

Turned out that your browser stopped supporting web sockets as proved in the [test page](http://websocketstest.com/).

Lots of things can cause such a thing (anti virus, corrupted browser update, incorrect proxy) none of those can be controlled or fixed by Stack Exchange.

Looks like that to this day, Chrome is the most reliable browser where it comes to supporting web sockets so to enjoy the full experience of live updates, it's better to use that browser.

Comment: I'm always on the `Newest` tab. and the problem still persists.

Comment: and how do you explain the new answers not showing ?

Comment: As far as I know, only "active" tab has the live updates. You probably used to be in that tab and moved to "newest" tab only recently.

Comment: I'm also wondering why firefox websockets stopped working all of a sudden even though I followed what was suggested [here](http://techdows.com/2010/12/turn-on-websockets-in-firefox-4.html) and found that network.websocket.enabled is already set to true. anyway thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd i am facing the same problem. i use chrome and on ubuntu. I tried the link you posted. it says websockets works for you. No http proxy. What do i do in this case?

Comment: @Raghunandan web sockets do not work today, it's fault on Stack Exchange side this time and [already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183070/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thank you for the info. I do see the newest tab. but i don't get the updates like 1 new activity.