# Stackoverflow not updating automatically

Tags: support, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [x questions with new activity / x new answers to this question not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166153/x-questions-with-new-activity-x-new-answers-to-this-question-not-working)

Previously I used to get live update on Stack Overflow, which means if someone posts a new question I will get update in already opened window as "1 new question..."

After firefox update, I am not getting live updates any more. I have to refresh to see the new questions. Also live updates from activities are  gone.

Comment: Use Chrome instead, FF probably doesn't really support web sockets.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It does.

Comment: Same issue..and not browser depended..I'm using Chrome!

Comment: @Bolt it's just that I see more and more reports here concerning Firefox. Maybe its settings are more strict then?

Comment: My auto update hasn't been working for a few days. Also the css has now stopped loading.

Comment: Are you by any chance using [BlockSite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/) or [BlockSite Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/blocksiteplus/) Add-ons? @Hoopdady FYA as well..

Comment: No I am not. The css is now working for me, but Its still not updating for me.