# Questions with new activity header no longer appears

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, web-sockets

For a few hours now, the heading that appears on the home page of Stack Exchange sites notifying of newly active questions has not been appearing. I have had to manually refresh in order to see new activity.

I have observed this on SF, SU and right here on mSO.

Upon hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome and looking around, it appears that the WebSockets connection to sockets.ny.stackexchange.com is failing, though Chrome doesn't tell me exactly why.

[image: sockets.ny.stackexchange.com fails]

On further investigation, I also seem to *not* be receiving notification of reputation changes, upvote/downvote changes, new comments notifications, flags, or inbox notifications.

Comment: [I am having the same problem.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/seU1Z.png)

Comment: What you get in [this page](http://websocketstest.com/)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd http://websocketstest.com/result/227406

Comment: So likely temporary downtime on Stack Exchange side. Happens to the best! :)

Comment: @Yannis The AJAX thingy needs to be notified of the updates before I can use them. There is no update without the web sockets.

Comment: @Antony Ah, I see.

Comment: This has been happening for me [since last night](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1396464#1396464). I assumed it was a temp outage and [only poked @StackStatus on Twitter about it](https://twitter.com/zopatista/status/342060231012020225).

Comment: Appears to be back now. Where's Nick with his technical explanations? :)

Comment: The socket is back, at least for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On our load balancer, we have multiple instances of HAProxy. One of these instances is dedicated to realtime updates (websockets) and somehow failed. After taking a core dump of that instance, I killed the process and started it again to get websockets working again.

Our current next steps are:

1. Keep investigating to try to figure out exactly what went wrong that caused websockets to stop responding
2. Set up more extensive monitoring for websockets so we have an alert when websockets stops responding

I will update this when I discover more information.

Comment: Cheers, I think this bug can be status-completed though.