# Notifications not appearing

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

Over the last few days, I've noticed that notifications such as "x questions with new activity" and general comment notifications don't appear particularly often.

Related screenshot showing that `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` is failing:

[image]

This seems to be [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183070/questions-with-new-activity-header-no-longer-appears) creeping up again.

Comment: Are you at a workplace, or behind a proxy? It looks like you're having issues reaching us on SSL.

Comment: @NickCraver Both at the workplace and from home has this issue. From home is just connecting to a router on a LAN. This was working 100% before (except when my connection is really shaky, which it isn't now). Both run Chrome 30, but tried IE 9 and it gives the same.

Comment: When you go to http://websocketstest.com/ what you get?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [It seems sufficiently happy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qEXr9.png).

Comment: Hmm.. so it's SSL issue as Nick mentioned above. Should have known better than to doubt him! ;)

Comment: @Dukeling if you visit this URL, what do you get? https://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ping

Comment: @NickCraver "StackExchange web-socket server on NY-WEB08"

Comment: hmm that means you're able to hit us fine on SSL, do you know what kind of proxy you're behind?

Comment: @Dukeling we have made some changes to attempt non-SSL if SSL fails, can you give it a try now?

Comment: @NickCraver It seems to be working better now. It doesn't do much for 2.5 minutes (can be reduced?), then starts working. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hUEc8.png). I don't know much about our network setup at work, but at home I'm not behind a proxy (at least not as far as I know) - websocketstest.com and amibehindaproxy.com seems to think I'm not.

Comment: We made some additional timeout changes on the SSL, can you tell me if that helped or hurt? I actually think we may have broken you again...if that's the case I know just how to fix it.

Comment: @NickCraver At the moment it seems to be doing better - the first connection doesn't appear to be failing anymore, or maybe the root cause was fixed, or maybe it's just temporary.

Comment: @Dukeling - can I close this as [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Oded Sure. I don't remember it happening again too recently.