# I am not getting the X New Questions box

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, status-norepro, google-chrome

This was asked over a year ago [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166153/x-questions-with-new-activity-x-new-answers-to-this-question-not-working) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183070/questions-with-new-activity-header-no-longer-appears), but it is happening to me now.

I did the [websocketstest](http://websocketstest.com/) and it gave me a [good result](http://websocketstest.com/result/346824).

> WebSockets seem to
>   Work for You!

The only failures were `HTTP Proxy` and `Antivirus` (I don't have one - Ubuntu).

Screenshots.

Before refreshing:
[image]

After refreshing:
[image]

There was no grey bubble - I should be seeing this (or similar).

[image]

It is broken on other sites too, including Meta AU and Meta Stack Exchange (if it is enabled on here?)

I also don't get the auto red alert that I have a new notification, and I don't think the rep is either. I have to refresh to see it...

Browser details:

```
Google Chrome   36.0.1985.125 (Official Build 283153)
OS  Linux
Blink   537.36 (@177902)
JavaScript  V8 3.26.31.8
Flash   14.0.0.145
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path    /home/tim/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "X new questions" alert is **not** enabled on Stack Overflow. I do see it on MSE.

Comment: @Chris Oh okay, it definitely should be on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That this isn't working on [so] is by design. Not working on sites it _should_, I can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Due to much larger amount of questions that go on on Stack Overflow, this feature is not active there.

It is working on the other sites, I've seen it in operation also here on Meta Stack Exchange just now.

Comment: Okay, so it is a problem at my end? And also my edit that I don't get any auto alerts? Is that the same problem, with my computer?

Comment: I can only assume. I have had Ask Ubuntu tabs open for the last hour and do have the real-time notifications coming up. Can you check in your browser developer tools, under the network section if websockets are working?

Comment: Yeah it was all working :) Restart fixed it... I'd had a few computer bugs (offline) ones, this was the only one in browser.