# High CPU usage when StackOverflow is left open for a long time

Tags: support, firefox, performance

Several times, I've noticed when I look at my computer in the morning, when it's been left on overnight, Firefox has high CPU usage (25% on this 4-core machine).

The first few times, I just restarted Firefox, and then it went back to low CPU usage (even though I've got it set to re-open all open tabs from before). After that happening several times, I tried closing tabs one-by-one, and found that it's the StackOverflow tab that was causing high CPU usage. After I've closed the tab, if I re-open it again then it is back to normal CPU usage. So it looks as though there's something about the SO page that causes high CPU usage after it's been open for a long time.

This is on Firefox 13 and 14, on Windows XP SP3, 32-bit. I haven't tried it with other browsers.

**Update**: I left both Firefox and Chrome on overnight with StackOverflow open. Chrome was fine. Firefox was again on high CPU usage. I found that just clicking reload for the SO page made the CPU usage go back down.

Comment: There seems to be no `cpu` tag or similar.

Comment: Perhaps you can try leaving firefox on over night, with only on tab (a SO page, obviously) open and protocol how long it takes for the cpu-usage to go up. On linux, I'd propose something like this: `while true; do sleep 10; ps aux | grep firefox >> ff.log; done`, on windows, I've no idea.

Comment: I too have noticed this. But I have more than just SO open, so I never blamed SO.

Comment: @Mysticial, maybe next time, try closing just the SO tab.

Comment: Are the [real time update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677) working? Firefox used cause high CPU load when it couldn't establish a WebSocket connection (due to constant and excessive retrying). I'm not sure if that's still the case though. (CC: @Mystical)

Comment: I have *many* SO tabs up in FFox v.latest all the time (24/7) and have never noticed this. Are you running any addons?

Comment: @slugster: Yes, I'm running a bunch of add-ons. DNSSD; English (Australian) dictionary; Firebug; Flashblock; IE Tab 2; Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant; Show Anchors 2; Xmarks

Comment: @Dennis Yes, real-time updates work. Funny thing is that on my other computer, FF doesn't lag, but vote-updates don't work. (but the "new activity" updates do... go figure...) Do you need to be logged into see vote-updates?

Comment: Well FWIW this _never_ happens in chrome, so it sounds like a FireFox bug to me,

Comment: @bitmask: Wouldn't this be better: `while true; do sleep 10s; date +%H:%M:%s >> ff.log; ps aux | grep firefox | grep -v grep >> ff.log`. Untested, though, as I don't have *nix here.

Comment: @UristMcBobby: Yes sure, that'd work (except you forgot the `done`) too, but you can determine the time from the number of lines with high load. Anyhow, the OP runs windows, so they'd have to write some batch-script.

Comment: @bitmask: Yeah...somewhere while writing that I thought "That done is missing..." but forgot about that again. And I take the bold claim that this is not possible with pure Windows and CMD...

Comment: (off-topic) @UristMcBobby Using `grep [f]irefox` saves you the extra `grep`.

Comment: @ShawnChin: Now that's a neat trick, thanks! For everyone else who's wondering how that works, it's easy ones you realize that `ps` shows `grep [f]irefox` as processname, which is of course not matched by `[f]irefox`. Neat.

Comment: To collect processor usage on WinXP easiest way is to use PerfMon to create a log of the total CPU time and current CPU % counters overnight (at whatever interval). With the addition of PowerShell (included from Win7): `while ($true) { start-sleep 30; get-process 'firefox' | % { "$(get-date),$($_.WorkingSet),$($_.TotalProcessorTime)"} | out-file -append "data.csv" }`. There are lots of other stats from `Get-Process` and even more from WMI that could be added.

Comment: I could log processor usage, but I don't know how that would enlighten us. This week I intend to check for issues with any extensions, by elimination. Tonight: all extensions disabled. Will report back with results.

Comment: I started a new Firefox profile, without any enabled extensions. Just one tab open with SO. This morning Firefox is on high CPU load. So I guess it's not any extension's fault. I clicked "reload" for the SO tab, and Firefox's CPU dropped to near-zero, and private memory usage dropped from 165 MB to 153 MB.

Comment: Thought I'd give an update. When FF is first opened up, a refresh of the SO homepage uses less than 1% CPU. After about 5 hours, a refresh spikes to 13% CPU (an entire core) for several seconds. So confirmed it is SO.