# What does the parenthesis and number (#) in front of the browser title mean?

Tags: support, notifications, live-refresh, activity, active

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

A picture says a thousand words:
[image]

While I think I already know the answer to question (number of new active posts that haven't been shown to you yet), I would like to know what this feature is called, so I can research more about it.

The first time I saw it, I thought it was the number of new notifications (similar to Facebook), so it seems a bit confusing to me.

Is this feature used in anything else than "new active posts on your currently opened 'active' tab"?

Comment: to the last question, yes, it is also being used in the chat rooms. And if someone directly send you a message, a `*` is added: `(1*)` :P

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby If closing this as duplicate will mean that this question will still be found when searching for a similar titled question, then I agree.

Comment: Yep, that is one of the reasons questions are closed as duplicates.  This can serve as a pointer for people who used similar search terms as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the new Real-time updates feature:

[New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Also called [live-refresh](/questions/tagged/live-refresh).