# Bug in reputation display

Tags: support, reputation, live-refresh

There is difference in the reputation on Stack Overflow in the site header and below the profile image. Is that a bug?

[image]

Comment: Refresh the page. :)

Comment: @Mysticial i know that after refreshing the page it will be ok would you tell me why this is happen is that is because of browser or programming ? and how to make it correct if problem like this is happen in my website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not a bug. The reputation number at the top of the page gets [live-updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox). But the reputation number under your gravatar does not.

When you loaded the page, you had 1620 rep. Then your reputation increased to 1628. The live-updates will update the number at the top, but not the number under your gravatar.

Comment: i have reloaded the page but there is no change in reputation ....i know that if user undo his action (reputation) there will be no change but there is nothing change regarding to the reputation under the reputation graph

Comment: When you reload it, the numbers should match. It should have nothing to do with what's in your reputation tab.