# What is sockets.ny.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support

I've been navigating using *Proxifier* these days, and I when I start visiting a few Stack Overflow pages, a lot of connections to http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com appear.

What is that site for?

Answer (score 7):

It's Stack Exchange's [`WebSocket`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) server, which is the technology used to provide live-updates.

For more info see [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Comment: True, and it's also "officially" mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Aha, was trying to find that link!