# Stack Overflow message mechanism

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

How does the Stack Overflow message mechanism work?

When I submit a post I can see it right away in the message list, yet when I open Stack Overflow on another machine, I don't see the post yet.

I know you can use CQRS to asynchronously store the message in a database through a backend,
but where does Stack Overflow store the message in the meantime?
Does it use websockets, cookies or some other mechanism?

I'm most interested the part where the message is also displayed when you open the questions list again. Where does it stay in the mean time?
I don't think stackoverflow is a single page website or is it?

Comment: +1, I think it's a valid question about architecture. I don't understand the close votes.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I think its because its almost a meta stackoverflow question, but since it is about programming architecture more than stackoverflow, I agree that its an acceptable question.

Comment: Duplicate of [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network).  The relevant bits appear to be [websockets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox), AJAX and caching.

Comment: @blahdiblah no, web sockets are used for the "live actions" e.g. showing "5 new posts" in the active tab however this question is about the fact there is no page refresh when posting stuff.

Comment: The answer is simple: AJAX. It's used all over the place thus you almost don't see full page reload.