# Real-time update to "newest" general questions instead of only on filtered questions

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

[New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677/178816)

I really like this feature. It is helpful and modern. It works great for comments, answers, and in specific question sections where it shows real-time questions as they become available.

Why is it that this feature is not being used in the "newest" tab of general (non filtered) questions?

Allow the "newest" tab for unfiltered questions to have a "load (x) new questions" link.

Comment: It does work on the newest tab. Always has for me, at least. **Edit:** On second thought, I've never seen it live-refresh on SO. I've seen it everywhere else though - beta sites and here on MSO. Maybe it's disabled there because of the high activity?

Comment: @animuson It is, and it's also disabled for the general "active" tab there too. It works on the "newest" and "active" tabs of things like tags, though.

Comment: Note that the answer you've linked to was superseded by the later one stating that behaviour was incorrect and has since been fixed.

Comment: @TimStone - You are correct, I edited to make the change.

Comment: @TimStone - Thank you for pointing out the differentiation between general and tagged (or otherwise filtered).