# How is the rep counter at the top real-time?

Tags: support, reputation, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Does it use AJAX? If so how often does it update? It seems pretty up-to-date when I see people voting on my posts. Does calling an AJAX request like that every second make a whole lot of difference to calling that same request every 5 minutes in terms of computer processing and latency?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this utilizes the socket functionally added recently... In the same way that vote counts update and new comments...

Comment: It's a live client/server connection using web sockets which were introduced as part of HTML5.

Comment: I don't think that post is the right dupe... It only talks about new questions...

Comment: @Lix: from the post: *As a few have mentioned below we are now experimenting with updating comment counts, votes on a post, and your **reputation score**.* (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Lix it introduced the use of web sockets in Stack Exchange; they later added more stuff so maybe that post need to be edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The counter uses web-sockets for that; here you can see them in the Chrome development console:

[image: web sockets]