# Are "What does SE use for [insert feature here]?" questions valid on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

I had a discussion about this with TGMCians [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240178/in-line-horizontal-paging?noredirect=1#comment786827_240178) (see screenshot at the bottom of the question), on a question that asks which control Stack Exchange uses for a specific feature. We did not agree whether they belong here or not, hence I'm asking here:

Are "What does Stack Exchange use for *[insert feature here]*?" questions valid on Meta Stack Exchange?

Screenshot of question and comment discussion:

> [image: Question and comment discussion]

Comment: So, "send me the algo/code" but rephrased to make it look like they actually care about how SE does it

Comment: @random The question I linked to is an example.

Comment: Yes, and you're making it look like the question over there isn't anything more than them posting in the wrong site. So instead of tacking on "in PHP" you'd be making "like how SE does it"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/10369

Comment: @random http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155637/how-is-the-rep-counter-at-the-top-real-time - it got couple of upvotes, decent answer, and was closed as dupe of a question introducing the feature because it's explained in there.