# What programming language is running behind Stack Overflow to push live data?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

This is just out of curiosity. I am seeing live data getting pushed and updated on Stack Overflow question pages.

Example -

- While I am seeing an answer posted, if the author is updating his answer or the question is modified, I see messages like - 'this answer is changed / updated, click to load'.
- The time keeps updating without a page refresh, minutes keeps increasing showing the time since the answer or question was posted.

I understand there are tools like [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and other server push technologies which makes this possible, but I am just thinking: What is Stack Overflow actually using and how are they doing this?

Comment: This offers a brief overview of what StackExchange uses: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: Thanks @Arran, this is helpful but still thinking about the live push, is it node.js or something in C# and asp.net, any guesses ??

Comment: node is not used in SO.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While I am seeing an answer posted, if the author is updating his answer or question is mofified I see messages like - 'this answer is changed / updated, click to load'.

It use to be done with [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) - JavaScript running on a schedule checking a web service end point to see if things have change. They may have move to use [Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) with a long polling fallback.

> The time keeps updating without page refresh, minutes keeps increasing showing the time since the answer or question was posted.

This is just client side JavaScript - the page has an ISO-8601 timestamp that is read by JavaScript in a `setInterval` (or `setTimeout` - not sure which one) loop that updates the display according to the amount of time that passed.

Comment: `setInternal` --> `setInterval`. I would have edited it myself but it wasn't > 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, very correct, following code snippet from their source code also says that they have moved to websockets now -
StackExchange.realtime.init('ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com');
                StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToInboxNotifications();
                                 StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToReputationNotifications('4');            
});