# Which technology is used by the stack exchange sites to notify a tagged page of new questions?

Tags: discussion, architecture

When I access tagged stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and leave it there for a while, I will get notified from my browser's tab if a new question has arrived.  In the tab, it will be a number between parentheses as in `(2)` for 2 new questions since I first accessed the page.

Which technology is being used to send those notifications without a page reload?

Comment: explained in this meta post - [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

Comment: Also [here is a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) of all the technologies used on the network.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript, baby.

It simply updates the title of the page after polling using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to see if there were changes. Chances are that this will change in the future to use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), if it isn't doing so already.

Comment: +1 for JavaScript, **baby**.