# Don't show new activity indicator for question already on top

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, live-refresh

I really like the new [websockets based updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) here on Meta. However, they are somewhat misleading, since the indicator shows up even when the most recently edited question is edited.

To elaborate, the page starts out looking like this:

[image]

Soon, I might see a notification that looks like this:

[image]

Now intuitively, the notification should mean that the order of the feed has in some way changed. It should only be shown when there are questions with more recent activity than the top one. Currently, it also shows for edits to the top question, in which case clicking the gray bar leaves the page basically unchanged.

It could be argued that the vote, answer and view counts are refreshed, along with any changes to the title, but I don't think this in itself warrants a notification.

**TL;DR**: Please do not show the notification if there is activity on a question that is already at the top of the feed.