# Refresh rates vs. connection time

Tags: discussion, support

I am not sure if this is a bug or a part of a feature I just overlooked. 
Before posting I've referred to: [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) 
(note: I am using google chrome )
Let's say I am on SO, and a new question is being asked. The title of the tab adjusts displaying the number (1) ( or more ) of new questions. 
However, when I am away from the browser for about 10-20 minutes, and more new questions were asked. Sometimes - the tab's title will not adjust/refresh to show the correct number. It will remain (x) although when I click the tab I can see there were more questions asked(x+y in the expandable drop down ).

Is this a bug? Or is there a time restriction for the tab's title to update only for the first X amount of minutes since my last activity? Or to show up to X amount of new questions? Or is there an assigned amount of refreshes per person/ip? Maybe its my firewall blocking it from working properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably your computer goes to sleep after some time.

This cuts Internet connectivity, meaning that web sockets and long polling fail.

This in turn means that JavaScript stops running.

This in turn means no live updates until you refresh and JavaScript can run again.

Comment: This in turn means a detailed answer.

Comment: This in turn means it's worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @Oded Good answer! How did i skip thinking about it? If only I mentioned that it happens only at work then I would have figured it out myself - the machine goes to sleep. Thanks