# Not getting red (1) when inbox has new message

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

I seem to have stopped receiving a notification in the upper left corner menu when somebody replies to me.  I stumbled over a few recent inbox messages when I visited my inbox for other reasons.

Is something broken, or does this happen because I probably left Stack Overflow open in my browser on a computer somewhere?

Edit: For the record, I do get a grey notification (1) when somebody proposes an edit or I earn a badge.

Update: As requested, here is a screenshot (Mac OSX Safari, but it essentially looks the same in Firefox on Linux and Windows.  Ugh, now I remember why I don't use Chrome -- the webkit browsers feel terribly slow!).

When I click open the menu, it shows the "hot questions" tab, but my inbox is there and contains some unread messages.  None of these are unread, though, but they look the same regardless.  (This time I scrolled down and noticed still more notifications further down in the inbox which I had overlooked before.)

[image: Inbox screenshot]

Comment: Make sure you do not have the inbox sitting open in a different tab, indeed. Happens to me all the time; if the inbox is open in another tab (or browser) it'll mark messages read there.

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure I don't. (I didn't even know you could!)

Comment: Your response to my comment got me a `(1)` red marker on my inbox, so things are working as expected for me.

Comment: Did you visit it in the responses tab of your profile? This can happen when someone edits in the @tripleee after they initially posted it

Comment: @MartijnPeters: Do you mean the "responses" tab of my profile, or is there an inbox interface I'm not aware of? Or do you mean having the dropdown menu dropped down so it displays my inbox?

Comment: @tripleee yeah, the profile page is what I mean

Comment: @RichardTingle: This is consistent over something like the 10 latest inbox messages, so it would be a massive statistical fluke if all of those had added `@tripleee` by editing their comment.  And some of them are comments to answers, which don't require the `@shoutout`.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see under the "inbox" tab of [MultiCollider SuperDropDown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackexchange-button/info)?

Comment: I don't see any connections from you to the socket server, did your ISP per chance put in a proxy that doesn't deal with websockets? Websockets need to work in order for the live update features (including live vote count updates) to work. What does [this test](http://websocketstest.com/) indicate?

Comment: @tripleee: I'm talking about the supercollider inbox dropdown.

Comment: Actually the issue must not be the server. The issue must be that you are reloading the page as perfectly as they are commenting! :D So when they press enter to comment of send feedback, you reload the page and find it there. Else you don't see it.

Comment: look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179283/refresh-rates-vs-connection-time). It may give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmafZeeshan: certainly not an issue of too eager reloading. Ten hours after I last visited this question I notice nine new comments to it in my inbox, but no notification.

Comment: @mehow, sorry, that doesn't look like my issue. My desktop computer at work stays on and connected for weeks, and other JavaScript-heavy sites like Gmail work fine, as does all other aspects of SO (question edited, new answer posted notification when I am reading a question while somebody posts an answer, and, as indicated above, the grey notification bubbles).

Comment: @hjpotter92: Thanks for asking; added a screenshot, as requested.

Comment: @TimPost: I get all green checkmarks both from OSX on my home ISP and Firefox on Windows via my employer's VPN.  I can still check Linux tomorrow if you like, but it seems to me like this is not the problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your first comment was spot on!  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll happily redact mine and accept yours instead.

Comment: @tripleee: there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you do not have the inbox sitting open in a different tab (same browser, different browser or even on a different computer).

Happens to me all the time; if the inbox is open in another tab then that tab'll mark messages read there.