# Why does SO not show "questions with new activity"

Tags: feature-request, new-questions

Many other StackExchange sites will notify you when there are *"questions with new activity"*. For instance, from [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]

Why does StackOverflow not have this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) it was intentionally done, but partially considered:

> We have also enabled updates on the questions page for the newest and
>   active tabs for all sites **except Stack Overflow**. If you open a
>   browser to these tabs you will receive instant notifications when new
>   questions are asked or answered.
>
> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to
>   limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab
>   will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

So, if you select a tag or a tag combination, you will have that "questions with new activity" shown (just in the "newest" and "active" tab).

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature exist also on SO, see [All Questions - Active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).

Comment: It doesn't work.  You can prove that yourself by opening the active tab on two different pages, and refreshing only one of them.

Comment: Ohh, alright. I see that.

Comment: Well, it does, if you select a tag or tag combination.