# The questions page gets weird when there's more than 500 questions with new activity

Tags: bug, recent-activity, live-refresh

Steps to reproduce:

1. Leave the [scifi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) front page open for a while.
2. Wait for [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10691/the-big-edit-event?cb=1) to kick a bunch of questions to the top.
3. Click the "X questions with new activity" banner (for X > 500).

Expected behavior:

The browser does a hard reload, or *something* other than the actual behavior.

Actual behavior:

The browser freezes up for a few seconds and then prompts me about an unresponsive script (tested: Firefox 51 on Windows 10).

Comment: Yeah, I got this happening too. I think this is what they call an "edge case" :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: In theory, you could trigger this on any site other than SO (which I think has the banner disabled) by just leaving the home page open overnight.

Comment: Well, if it could happen on any site, then isn't it something for main meta rather than here? Anyway I've upvoted this as just another example of "*wow*, we got some crazy editing statistics this weekend" for posterity.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127203/152859